# Angular7: how to get data from a server in JSON format and put it into an array of Objects

Tags: arrays, json, angular7

I'm starting using Angular7 and I followed the tutorials for building an application getting input from a web service and putting the result in an array of objects.

It works as long the data already come in the form of an array.
It stops working when the data come in JSON format.

The problem is that all answers I found on forums around the web includes the use of the map function and, when I use it, after including the corresponding definition file (from `rxjs/operators`), I always get the error

> "groups.map is not a function".

Another problem is that I continue finding solutions for old versions of Angular, which obviously do not work anymore.

I am working with Angular 7.2.11, typescript 3.2.4, rxjs 6.3.3 and webpack 4.29.0 and not with any of the numerous previous versions.

The problem I am facing should be a very common one: getting data from a REST server in JSON format (nested and typed) and putting the data into the data structures (classes) the app needs in order to perform the various tasks.

Someone suggested to abandon the TrueScript classes and to work directly with the JSON object returned by the `http.get` call.
If that is indeed the best practice, I would like to know how to handle the JSON object in the example I posted.

I tried to completely simplify the call to the http get:

```
getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {

    this.http.get(this.groupsUrl)
      .subscribe(data => {console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And the web console shows me the correctly loaded array "groups" in the `groups.service.ts`.
The next step, though, which is mapping the array into the app's objects, does not work.

This is the class:

```
export class Group {  
    public dn: string;
    public cn: string[];
    public name: string[];
    public member: string[];

    constructor(args: {
        dn: string,
        cn: string[],
        name: string[],
        member: string[]
    }) {
        this.dn = args.dn
        this.cn = args.cn;
        this.name = args.name;
        this.member = args.member;
    }
}
```

This is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Group } from './group';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class GroupService {

  private groupsUrl = '../assets/groups.json';

  groups: Group[];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService) { }

    getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {

    return this.http.get<Group[]>(this.groupsUrl).pipe(
      map(groups => groups.map(groupJson => new Group(groupJson))));
  }
}
```

This is the component:

```
  getGroups(): void {
    this.groupService.getGroups()
      .subscribe(groups => this.groups = groups)
  }
```

This is the json file:

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "dn": "CN=mycn,OU=Groups,OU=valiant,OU=Organizations,DC=rag,DC=net",
            "cn": [
                "mycn"
            ],
            "name": [
                "mycn"
            ],
            "member": [
                "changz",
                "gorkony",
                "martoks",
                "azetburn"
            ]
        },

...

    ]
}
```

For those having the same problem, I post here the solution built with the help of user Hari Prathap:

```
  groups: Group[];

  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return {
          errMessage: res.errmessage,
          errCode: res.errcode,
          groups: res.data.groups.map(obj => new Group(obj))
        };
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfig().subscribe(ret => {
      console.log("errCode", ret.errCode);
      console.log("errMessage", ret.errMessage);
      console.log("groups", ret.groups);

      this.groups = ret.groups;

      console.log("Group 1", this.groups[1]);

    });
  }
```

The key to solving the problem has been pointing out the fact that the return value of the http.get function represents the entire response from the REST server and not the groups part I was interested in.

The groups part is accessible using the "." operator, although neither the IDE nor the compiler know the exact structure of the JSON being read at compile time.

The compiler, in fact, issues an ERROR, but the code works nonetheless.
The groups extracted this way from the response can then be mapped into an array of objects having the same structure of the array found in the JSON file.

This error can be avoided by using this notation:

```
groups: res["data"].groups.map(obj => new Group(obj))
```

Comment: Is groups in `map(groups => groups.map(groupJson => new Group(groupJson))));` an object or array? If groups is an object, then groups.map will not work.

Comment: groups is an array of Group, it is defined this way:

`groups: Group[];`

Answer (score 0):

@Lastshaman67,

The problem is pipe map method gets entire object not just groups from json file. I have created a codesandbox for your reference.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/n7xjkrplvl

Comment: In the rxjs map function, you can do data.groups. In your case, return this.http.get<Group[]>(this.groupsUrl).pipe(
      map(groups => groups.groups.map(groupJson => new Group(groupJson)))); You can rename groups to groupObj or data for readability

Comment: I see. I forked your codesandbox and I succeeded in modifying getConfig in order to return an object[] with the groups:
`
  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res.data.groups.map(obj => obj);
      })
    );
  } 
`

Comment: My JSON file is a little more complicated, though:

{
    "errcode": "0",
    "errmessage": "OK",
    "data": {
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "abc",
                "description": "def",
                "members": [
                    "ghi",
                    "jkl",
                    "nop",
                    "qrs"
                ]
            },

Is it possible to use map to "cast" the response data into an something like:

export interface GroupInterface {
  errcode: string;
  errmsg: string;
  group: string[];
}

Comment: You can format your response as per your need in rxjs map function. Please refer https://codesandbox.io/embed/n7xjkrplvl. I have updated my sandbox

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clarified everything for me.
Now, I modified your code in order to return in the variable groups the entire array contained in JSON under groups.

How can I use the map function to map that array into an array of objects of the Group class (that is Group[])?

Comment: It seems to be working now: https://codesandbox.io/embed/ww08wr035l
I use map to convert the group array into Group[].
Thanks a lot Hari Prathap.

Comment: I am happy it helps you.